# TSQL - exclude users who who meet ONLY criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The goal is to exclude, or otherwise flag the customers who **ONLY** have records of ItemNumber like '9%'.

```
    CustomerID  ItemNumber
    85610           99
    85611           11
    85611           99
    85612           13
    85612           11
    85612           98
    85613           98
    85613           99
```

In this example, CustomerIDs 86510 and 86513 should be excluded, or flagged, as the ONLY ItemNumbers associated with their records are like '9%'.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT CustomerID, ItemNumber
FROM dbo.table AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.table 
    WHERE CustomerID = t.CustomerID 
    AND ItemNumber NOT LIKE '9%'
);
```

Comment: +1 - very clever. On a related note, is there a performance gain in using `SELECT 1` on the `EXISTS` instead of a real column of the table?

Comment: @Lamak no, no performance difference. SQL Server knows that anything inside an EXISTS does not need to be materialized. You can put SELECT * or SELECT any column and it won't change the plan a bit. I like to use a constant because then it's quite clear to the reader that this subquery does not select any data.

Comment: I think the Query Processor will do a bit of work with a column or *, but the resulting plan will be the same, and there will be no difference at execution time.  The compile-time difference is probably unnoticealble, but some people have style preferences.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm, and was very clearly written and easily translated to production code.  Thank you so much.

Also, how would one word this issue elegantly? I was, and still am at a loss.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't know that being able to formulate this as a word problem is all that valuable. If you want help solving a query you're having, we do much, much better with sample data and desired results. The word problem usually just gets in the way.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID
FROM Table T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerID FROM Table WHERE CustomerId = T.CustomerId AND ItemNumber NOT LIKE '9%')
```

Comment: Aaron has ended his query with ); which is exactly how I feel right now.

Comment: There is a crucial difference on both answers though. Aaron is using `NOT LIKE '9%'` and its correct, you are using `LIKE '9%'` and that won't work as expected

Comment: Oh and +1 because I'm a sportsman and your comment made me laugh.

Comment: Well, now your answer is right :-). @AaronBertrand - yeap, is fixed now

Comment: Yes, you can downvote the +1 if you like haha, I realized yours was actually right because I completely misread.

EDIT: I'm referring to how I was filtering out things that had anything starting with '9%' instead of what was asked, which was filtering out anything that had ONLY rows starting with '9%'.

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber LIKE '9%' THEN 1 END) = 1
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber NOT LIKE '9%' THEN 1 END) IS NULL
```

Comment: The downside here would be that in order to get the `ItemNumber`s, its need to be joined against the table again, right?. If that column weren't needed, would this perform better than the `EXISTS`?

Comment: @Lamak - It is one scan through the table so might be. Wouldn't like to guess without setting up some test data to compare the two and trying different combinations of indexes and data distributions.

Comment: @Lamak - For the OP's example data and following table definition `CREATE TABLE #YourTable (CustomerID INT, ItemNumber INT, PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID, ItemNumber))` I get [these plans and estimated costs.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Xul.jpg). Get rid of the index and [I get these plans and costs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8pOA0.jpg)

Comment: Though without the index the `NOT EXISTS` plan is doing repeated full scans so that plan will start to get pretty expensive when the tables are larger and I guess that plan will need to change to a different join type and the advantage will likely disappear or be reversed (merge join will need two sorts)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tc(CustomerID int,ItemNumber varchar(10))

INSERT INTO tc
VALUES(85610,99),
    (85611,11),
    (85611,99),
    (85612,13),
    (85612,11),
    (85612,98),
    (85613,98),
    (85613,99)

select CustomerID from tc 
where ItemNumber like '9%'
group by CustomerID 

except

select CustomerID from tc 
where ItemNumber not like '9%'
group by CustomerID
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm missing something, why not just include a `WHERE` clause that has `ItemNumber NOT LIKE '9%'`

Comment: Yes, I think you're missing something. The reason your suggestion won't work is because a simple where clause will include customers that have an ItemNumber of 99, but may also have an ItemNumber of 11 in a different row.